# Numpad View acting different in Edit mode and Object Mode?

Tags: 3d-view

Using the numpad to switch views works fine in object mode, but when I switch to edit mode it is a random view and skewed.

Here is the front view in object mode after hitting the NUMPAD 1 button
[image]

and the same everything in edit mode, hitting NUMPAD 1, which seams to rotate and view the bottom.

[image]

Comment: That's very odd.. Is it possible you are pressing Shift+Numpad 1 or something (some kind of input issue)? Or could you upload your .blend so we can see if it's some sort of setting or bug in blender?

Comment: What kind of orientation is that if you use Shift+Numpad 1/3/7? Seems odd to me.

Comment: @CoDEmanX Are you asking me? (I was a little confused by your comment). I was thinking that perhaps the OP had a face selected or something (Shift+numpad1/3/7 will align the view to the selection).

Comment: Both screenshots say you are in user view, any chance you are using non-blender input options? the 3DMax and Maya input presets don't respond to numpad-1 and shift-numpad-1 keeps saying user view when it does go to side view.

Comment: I wanted to know what it does, so the answer is "align to selection", which is still odd - why would it use such weird viewport orientations if the default cube with no rotation is selected? Is it on purpose? (I guess I should make this a new question...)

Comment: @CoDEmanX The orientation would make sense if the selection was a face on the cylinder above the cube.

Comment: I have switched the NUMPAD 1/3/7 to be front, right, and top, respectively, so it's not SHIFT related. It does seem like having something selected is the cause of this, is there anyway to turn off align to selection so that the shortcut is always the same? Weirdly though, even with nothing selected pressing front view does show the front view, but is rotated upside down in edit mode...

Comment: Strange. There is always an active element, which is usually the last selected (even if it is not selected, it's still active). If you select another element and then de-select everything, does the orientation from pressing numpad 1 in edit mode change?

Comment: just tried jumping in and out of edit mode, also adding another cube, and it seems that the only key that works properly throughout is NUMPAD 3, for right view. My top and front view keys in edit mode for the box/cylinder switch to front and bottom views, respectively, and for a newly created cube, top and front keys switch to a rotated left view and rotated front view, respectively. Deselecting didn't help, is there a way to "deactivate" everything?

Comment: Not that I know of. tbh the selection *shouldn't* have anything to do with the view to begin with.. I have no idea what could be causing this. Does the behavior change based on the selection? What happens if you reload factory settings? File > reload factory settings. This will only be temporary, when you restart blender, you will have any custom setup back the way it was.

Comment: Thank you! The problem seems to be somewhere within the 3ds max profile, as when I switched to factory default it works fine.